# Understanding Dart private class

Tags: dart, flutter

In Flutter we commonly have something like this:

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyState createState() => _MyState();
}

class _MyState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  void doSomething() => print('hi');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

So `_MyState` is declared with a `_`, which makes it library private.

**So how come the Flutter render engine can use `_MySate` if it's sopposed to be private?**

It's funny because I can access `doSomething()` from other files, but if I make it `_doSomething()`, I can't access it anymore...So how come I can access a public method from a private class, but I can't access a private method from a private class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53495089/10269042

Comment: ohhh that's interesting, a bit unexpected as well...I will mark it as a duplicate, thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While `_MyState` is private, `StatefulWidget` and `State` are not.

The framework doesn't manipulate `_MyState`, it manipulates these lower layer that he has access to, with a well-defined prototype.

This basically sums up into:

```
StatefulWidget widget;
State foo = widget.createState();

foo.initState();
final newWidget = foo.build(this);
...
```

Comment: This was my initial theory...but I still can access `doSomething()` from another dart file, should't it be forbidden access?

Comment: The class is private, the method is not.

Comment: Oh, but what's the point of having a private class if it's contents can be used by other files? (As far as I understand each file is a library)....I guess I am under the conclusion that everything under a private class will be private, even its instantiation

Comment: I suspect that the intent is to support cases where you don't want to expose a class but you do want to expose one or more of its methods. That seems like a plausible situation. You can make your private class's methods private _likeAnyOtherMethod.