# Are variables inside the state class supposed to be private always?

Tags: flutter, dart

In Flutter, inside a state widget are the state variables supposed to be private or we can let them  be public ? Intuition says we must make them private . But many people dont do that ? Why?
The official counter app has `_counter`  marked as private?

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter, as far as I'm aware. The State class itself is private (because of the underscore in the class name: `_MyHomePageState`), so nothing can access the variables inside whether they were private or not.

Comment: Thanks for answering but private class does not means all its variables are private . Please read here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53495089/dart-should-the-instance-variables-be-private-or-public-in-a-private-class